# Rate of convergence in distribution

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Imagine a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in [0,1] converging *pointwise* (*i.e,* sure convergence) to the random variable $X$, with convergence factor $\lambda$:
$$
|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|=O(\lambda^n),\quad\text{for all }\omega\in\Omega=[0,1]
$$
It is also clear that sure convergence implies convergence in distribution: 
$X_n\overset{\mathcal D}{\rightarrow}X$.

**Question**: can the convergence factor of  $\,\overset{\mathcal D}{\rightarrow}\,$ be different than $\lambda$? My rough intuition is that convergence in distribution could potentially be orders of magnitude faster, being convergence in distribution less demanding than sure convergence.

I found out that the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) $W_1$ metrizes *weak convergence* in our particular case (because our space is bounded in $\mathbb R$), so $W_1$ can be used in this context as a metric to analyze weak convergence. Moreover, since we are in $\mathbb R$, $W_1$ can be written as:

$$
W_1(P_n,P)=\int_0^1|F_n(x)-F(x)|dx,
$$

where $\{P_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $P$ are corresponding probability measures.

So my question is whether there is a possibility to obtain something like

$$
W_1(P_n,P)=o(\lambda^n)
$$

meaning that convergence in distribution is much faster than sure convergence in this context.

I have thought of using the transformation

$$
W_1(P_n,P)=\int_0^1|F^{-1}_n(y)-F^{-1}(y)|dy,
$$
by defining $F^{-1}$ suitably, because this formula involves distances in our domain $[0,1]$, which are bounded by $\lambda^n$.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|=O(\lambda^n)$..? Clearly, $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq C \lambda^n$ but in general $C$ will depend on $\omega$. Do you assume that $C$ can be chosen independently of $\omega$...?

Comment: You're right. As you suggest, $C$ may depend on $\omega$. But it can be bounded in our case because $\omega\in[0,1]$. So $C$ is a constant independent of $\omega$.

Comment: Note that $C(\omega)<\infty$ for each $\omega \in [0,1]$ does, in general, not imply $\sup_{\omega \in [0,1]} C(\omega)<\infty$.

Comment: Our $C$ is fixed, finite, independent of $\omega$. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The rate of convergence in distribution is, in general, not strictly faster than the rate of pointwise convergence. Consider for instance $X_n(\omega) := \lambda^n$ for fixed $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $X(\omega):=0$ and $$f(x) := \min\{|x|,1\}.$$  Clearly, $$|\mathbb{E}f(X_n)-\mathbb{E}f(X)| = \lambda^n,$$ and therefore $W_1(P_n,P) \geq \lambda^n$. Consequently, $W_1(P_n,P)$ has the same rate of convergence as the pointwise convergence.

Comment: @saz, thanks a lot for the answer, which shows that the rate of convergence in distribution is, in general, not strictly faster than the rate of pointwise convergence. However, my interest is to know whether there are particular examples where convergence in distribution is strictly faster. I can't find one!